# Are the .order method parameters in ActiveRecord sanitized by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to pass a string into the .order method, such as

```
Item.order(orderBy)
```

I was wondering if orderBy gets sanitized by default and if not, what would be the best way to sanitize it.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string value? I imagine `Item.order("?", orderBy)` should sanitize, but there may be a better way depending on what you're string is

Comment: @ctshryock that will just result in a `select * from items order by ?, orderBy`

Comment: @DylanMarkow I was thinking `.order("created_at > ?", orderBy)` or similar, but that's probably only good for `where` (at least not `order`)?

Comment: @ctshryock Yeah, it seems like `order` strictly passes a string without any processing.

Comment: the string value could be any column of the table. I'm using this for an API and I want to enable the users to sort the retrieved items by passing a parameter. It seemed to me that where sanitizes, but nor order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The order does not get sanitized. This query will actually drop the Users table:

```
Post.order("title; drop table users;")
```

You'll want to check the `orderBy` variable before running the query if there's any way `orderBy` could be tainted from user input. Something like this could work:

```
items = Item.scoped
if Item.column_names.include?(orderBy)
  items = items.order(orderBy)
end
```

Answer (score 11):

They are not sanitized in the same way as a `.where` clause with `?`, but you can use `#sanitize_sql_for_order`:

```
sanitize_sql_for_order(["field(id, ?)", [1,3,2]])
# => "field(id, 1,3,2)"

sanitize_sql_for_order("id ASC")
# => "id ASC"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_order

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the best way of doing this. However I'm not sure this ActiveRecord method was available 3 years ago :)

Comment: This does actually very little to sanitize the order-part. Something like `sanitize_sql_for_order("id; drop table somethings") will still behave unexpectedly, and worst case delete the table :/

Comment: Check source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d15527800fbc199b969019c665226f836d8fedce/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L64 in case of a single string it will just do _nothing_ :(

Comment: Was `sanitize_sql_for_order` introduced in Rails 5? Can't seem to find it in Rails 3 or 4 documentation.

Comment: What's the right way to call sanitize_sql_for_order (in a controller)? I'm using `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_for_order, "thing_id = ?", thing_id)`, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 11):

Just to update this for Rails 5+, as of this writing, passing an array into `order` will (attempt to) sanitize the right side inputs:

```
Item.order(['?', "'; DROP TABLE items;--"])
#=> SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY '''; DROP TABLE items;--'
```

This will trigger a deprecation warning in Rails 5.1 about a "Dangerous query method" that will be disallowed in Rails 6.  If you know the left hand input is safe, wrapping it in an `Arel.sql` call will silence the warning and, presumably, still be valid in Rails 6.

```
Item.order([Arel.sql('?'), "'; DROP TABLE items;--"])
#=> SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY '''; DROP TABLE items;--'
```

**It's important to note that unsafe SQL on the left side will be sent to the database unmodified.  Exercise caution!**

If you know your input is going to be an attribute of your model, you can pass the arguments as a hash:

```
Item.order(column_name => sort_direction)
```

In this form, ActiveRecord will complain if the column name is not valid for the model or if the sort direction is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like the following:

```
@scoped = @scoped.order Entity.send(:sanitize_sql, "#{@c} #{@d}")
```

Where Entity is the model class.

Answer (score 1):

### Extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` with `sanitized_order`.

Taking [Dylan's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898249/293280) I decided to extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` in order to add a chainable method that will automatically sanitize the `order` params that are passed to it.

Here's how you call it:

```
Item.sanitized_order( params[:order_by], params[:order_direction] )
```

And here's how you extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` to add it:

**config/initializers/sanitized_order.rb**

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation

  # This will sanitize the column and direction of the order. 
  # Should always be used when taking these params from GET.
  #
  def sanitized_order( column, direction = nil )
    direction ||= "ASC"

    raise "Column value of #{column} not permitted."       unless self.klass.column_names.include?( column.to_s ) 
    raise "Direction value of #{direction} not permitted." unless [ "ASC", "DESC" ].include?( direction.upcase ) 

    self.order( "#{column} #{direction}" )
  end

end
```

It does two main things:

1. It ensures that the `column` parameter is the name of a column name of the base `klass` of the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

   In our above example, it would ensure `params[:order_by]` is one of `Item`'s columns.
2. It ensures that the direction value is either "ASC" or "DESC".

It can probably be taken further but I find the ease of use and DRYness very useful in practice when accepting sorting params from users.

Comment: In Rails 5, this can be accomplished via `Item.order(params[:order_by] => params[:order_direction])`.  ActiveRecord will complain if the column (left side) or direction (right side) are not valid.

Comment: If the relation being ordered isn't directly an active record class what happens?  For instance if I use it on @article.comments.where(parent_id: nil) or the like.