# Is the following code snippet vulnerable to SQL injection in Rails 5?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

Is the following code snippet vulnerable to SQL injection in Rails 5 if the order parameter is not sanitized? I've tried testing it using the example provided in https://rails-sqli.org/rails5 but an ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference exception is raised. Does that mean the code is safe against SQLi?

```rb
@exports = Export.for_public.order(params[:order] || 'created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the .order method parameters in ActiveRecord sanitized by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897239/are-the-order-method-parameters-in-activerecord-sanitized-by-default)

Comment: @razvans, I think this https://medium.com/@mitsun.chieh/activerecord-relation-with-raw-sql-argument-returns-a-warning-exception-raising-8999f1b9898a actually answers it better. Thank you for your contribution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question here https://medium.com/@mitsun.chieh/activerecord-relation-with-raw-sql-argument-returns-a-warning-exception-raising-8999f1b9898a.